# extracting linear model coefficients into a vector within a loop

Tags: r, loops, lm

I am trying to create sample of 200 linear model coefficients using a loop in R. As an end result, I want a vector containing the coefficients.

```
for (i in 1:200) {        
  smpl_5 <- population[sample(1:1000, 5), ]
  model_5 <- summary(lm(y~x, data=smpl_5))         
}
```

I can extract the coefficients easy enough, but I am having trouble outputting them into a vector within the loop. Any Suggestions?

Comment: See the help file `?coef` for extracting coefficients. Assuming you are going to be storing more than one coefficient from each model, you will either need to store them in a `list` (recommended) or multiple vectors (one for each coefficient). You will also want to initialize your object to the correct length before entering the loop (e.g. `coefList <- list(NULL); length(coefList) <- 200`).

Comment: @nrussell - since all models have the same structure (i.e. an intercept and the coefficient for `x` are estimated), the coefficients matrices will all be of identical dimension, so an array is also suitable.

Comment: @jbaums Agreed, I was just throwing out the first couple of suggestions that came to mind which would require little modification to the OP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replicate` for this if you like. In your case, because the number of coefficients is identical for all models, it'll return an array as shown in the example below:

```
d <- data.frame(x=runif(1000))
d$y <- d$x * 0.123 + rnorm(1000, 0, 0.01)
coefs <- replicate(3, {
  xy <- d[sample(nrow(d), 100), ]
  coef(summary(lm(y~x, data=xy)))
})

coefs

# , , 1
# 
#                Estimate  Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 0.001361961 0.002091297  0.6512516 5.164083e-01
# x           0.121142447 0.003624717 33.4212114 2.235307e-55
# 
# , , 2
# 
#                Estimate  Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 0.003213314 0.001967050  1.63357 1.055579e-01
# x           0.118026828 0.003332906 35.41259 1.182027e-57
# 
# , , 3
# 
#                Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 0.003366678 0.001990226  1.691606 9.389883e-02
# x           0.119408470 0.003370190 35.430783 1.128070e-57
```

Access particular elements with normal array indexing, e.g.:

```
coefs[, , 1] # return the coefs for the first model

#                Estimate  Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 0.001361961 0.002091297  0.6512516 5.164083e-01
# x           0.121142447 0.003624717 33.4212114 2.235307e-55
```

So, for your problem, you could use:

```
replicate(200, { 
  smpl_5 <- population[sample(1:1000, 5), ]
  coef(summary(lm(y~x, data=smpl_5))) 
})
```